# How do I view a list of packages installed in a DevHub org using the SFDX CLI?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, ci, dev-hub, unlocked-package

When I run:

```
sfdx force:package:installed:list -u DevHub
```

(where DevHub is the alias of my production org, which IS enabled as Dev Hub and also has 2GP enabled)

I receive this error:

```
    ERROR running force:package:installed:list:  sObject type 'InstalledSubscriberPackage' is not supported.

    Try this: Packaging is not enabled on this org. Verify that you are authenticated to the desired org and try again. Otherwise, contact Salesforce Customer Support for more information.
```

This command works on sandboxes, scratch orgs, and a 30-day trial devhub org, but not our current production org.

The goal is to get the packageVersionIds of the packages installed in our org and also to understand how the metadata of the packaging system works within the context of the DevHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the same thing in my Org, I have enabled the DevHub and 2GP, then installed a package and tried to fetch the installed package details using CLI command.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, it is working fine for me. There may two case:-

1. Run sfdx:force:org:list command and recheck the authenticated org. Check if 2GP has been enabled or not. If you run this command, the result will come like this:-

[image]

2. If everything is right and yet not working fine, You should raise a case with Salesforce DX team.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Download AppExchange Packages` System Permission for your Profile or Permission Set. It needs to be enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The command as of today to list the packages is                           `sfdx package:installed:list --target-org Target-Org`
Should be run within the project.